# Getting tweets from a certain period where user was mentioned

Tags: api, twitter, get

I'm using the twitter API and would like to get all tweets from a given time period where a given user was mentioned.

I tried the **search API** with the **until parameter** where I could get the tweets for the previous 7 days from the date which is not the best, but fine. However, in this case the API only returns the number of tweets without the details.

Any ideas how to do it or what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You are not posting code is what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Strange, https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets says it should return tweet objects. Are you sure you implemented it correctly? Which library are you using? Maybe there is a fault in its implementation. Another library could therefore be the solution.

Don't know whether this satisfies your needs, but you could also try to use the [GET statuses/mentions_timeline API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/mentions_timeline) . This API returns up to 800 tweets in which the user was mentioned.

EDIT, based on the comments on this post:

You are doing 2 things wrong, namely:

- As stated in the [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets) the until parameter has a 7 day limit. So you can only retrieve up to 7 days of tweets.
- Furthermore, you are making incorrect use of the since parameter. The since parameter specifies since this tweet (so the id of the tweet), not since this date.

Please read the documentation carefully. It is written very precisely and contains all the answers you probably need.

Comment: Thanks @Pieter. I don't use the mentions timeline API because that works only for the authenticating user. For testing I'm using the [Twitter API Console](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/tools/console). Here is an example: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=volkswagen%20since%3A2015-09-09%20until%3A2015-09-17&lang=en

Comment: Thanks @Pieter. I know the documentation mentions the since_id though I was using both since and until for date as part of the 'q' parameter because I've found an example where it worked. Last question - the 7 days limit is from the current date or from the date is given for 'until' value?